# Получить текст внутри класса title

Tags: javascript, html

Уже меня есть таблица, которая генерируется php. ЕЕ структура:

```html
<tr>
  <td class="search_table_position col-md-1">
    <? echo $rank ?>
  </td>
  <td class="search_table_img col-md-2"> <img width="150px" height="150px" src="<? echo $image ?>" alt=""> </td>
  <td class="search_table_title col-md-8">
    <h3 class="name">
      <? echo $title ?>
    </h3>
    <p>
      <? echo $description ?>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="search_table_rating col-md-1">
    <i class="fa fa-star" style="color:yellow" aria-hidden="true">
                </i>
    <?echo $rating ?>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Я хочу по клику на элемент таблицы "tr" вытянуть значение, находящееся внутри "search_table_title" в "h3 class = "name".
Можно ли это сделать средствами  жс без фреймворков?

[image: как выглядит таблица]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation):

```js
document.querySelector('.table').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.target.closest('tr').querySelector('h3.name').innerText);
})
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="search_table_position col-md-1">
      RANK
    </td>
    <td class="search_table_img col-md-2"> <img width="150px" height="150px" src="<? echo $image ?>" alt=""> </td>
    <td class="search_table_title col-md-8">
      <h3 class="name">
        TITLE
      </h3>
      <p>
        DESCRIPTION
      </p>
    </td>
    <td class="search_table_rating col-md-1">
      <i class="fa fa-star" style="color:yellow" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
      RATING
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```